# In Windows 10, how to create custom mouse button shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, copy-paste, mouse-click

Does anyone know how to change the mouse button shortcuts?

I have mouse with 6 buttons and I need one of those buttons to do the same thing as Ctrl+V does.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you install the driver and/or software, it will provide an .exe in which you can make these changes.

Install the software, and open it and see if it provides anything. Failing that, go to Control Panel and open Mouse to see if you have the option.

Alternatively you may be able to use AutoHotKey

https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

```
General 
LButton Left mouse button
RButton Right mouse button
MButton Middle or wheel mouse button

Advanced    
XButton1    4th mouse button. Typically performs the same function as Browser_Back.
XButton2    5th mouse button. Typically performs the same function as Browser_Forward.

Wheel   
WheelDown   Turn the wheel downward (toward you).
WheelUp Turn the wheel upward (away from you).
WheelLeft
WheelRight  
[v1.0.48+]: Scroll to the left or right.

Requires Windows Vista or later. These can be used as hotkeys with some (but not all) mice which have a second wheel or support tilting the wheel to either side. In some cases, software bundled with the mouse must instead be used to control this feature. Regardless of the particular mouse, Send and Click can be used to scroll horizontally in programs which support it.
```

Comment: i want to paste stuff with button 6 and its on middle of my mouse. It is DPI button.
I didnt understood anything from that text with gray background.
How to make that script in autohotkey?